# Is it possible to start connector without JSON in Kubernetes kafka-connect

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I had startup the connector in kubernetis cluster with the plugin registered.Is it possible to start the connectors without REST API ie Json values.
Specifying the values in HELM

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Landoop Kafka Connect UI or Confluent Control Center, but both are still using the same Kafka Connect REST API behind the scenes